# Missing dependencies in chromeos linux development environment

Tags: raspberry-pi, chrome-os

I am trying to get the rpi-imager utility working on a chromebook. I enabled the linux development environment, downloaded the .deb package file from the raspi website, and tried installing with apt:

```
~$ sudo apt install ./imager_1.6.2_amd64.deb 
Note, selecting 'rpi-imager' instead of './imager_1.6.2_amd64.deb'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 rpi-imager : Depends: libgcc-s1 (>= 3.0) but it is not installable
              Depends: libqt5core5a (>= 5.12.2) but 5.11.3+dfsg1-1+deb10u4 is to be installed
              Recommends: udisks2 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Is there a straightforward way for me to get libgcc or libqt into my chrome LDE to resolve these dependencies? I tried googling for a chromeos PPA to add, but didn't turn anything up.

I am familiar with crouton, but I'd like to avoid setting that up just to image an sd card.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue of missing `libgcc-s1` for an unrelated install by installing GCC-10.2.1.  Although `apt` says that it cannot get these files I was able to download both from [this gcc repository](http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/g/gcc-10/).

There's probably a way to get apt to use that repository but I didn't do that I manually downloaded and installed these two files:

- `gcc-10-base_10.2.1-6+rpi1_armhf.deb`
- `libgcc-s1_10.2.1-6+rpi1_armhf.deb`

The other package you need does not appear to be there though.

Not sure if this is simpler than using crouton, or if it will help with the other package, but maybe it's halfway there for you.